# How to output lowest number in array (also to see if I'm doing this right)

Tags: c#, arrays, max, average, minimum

Back with another C# question.

Here's my current task:

> **Problem Definition:**
>   A computer program is required to read the daily hours parked by customers. There are 30 entries for customer’s parking hours (integer numbers) stored in a data file ‘hours.txt’. You are required to read the file and store the data in an array. Calculate the highest, lowest and average of the daily parking hours.
>
> **Sample Data:**
>   30 parking hours: {8, 24, 9, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8, 8, 9, 7, 9, 15, 6, 1, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8}
>
> Highest parking hours = 24
>
> Lowest parking hours = 1
>
> Average parking hours = 9.13
>
> **Overall Tasks:**
>   Read the data file ‘hours.txt’ into an array of data type integer
>
> Find highest value
>
> Find lowest value
>
> Calculate the average
>
> Output the array of hours, highest, lowest and average (formatted to 2 decimal places)
>
> **Note:** Since the topic of “files” is not covered until Session 6, for now, declare your array and assign the numbers as shown below
>   int[] hoursArray = {8, 24, 9, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8, 8, 9, 7, 9, 15, 6, 1, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8};
>   In session 6 you will need to modify your code so the data is read from the hours.txt file.

So from this I gather I need to run a program that spits out the average, highest, and lowest of the hours entered. Note that it says to use the data from a text file, but further down says that is for a different topic, so I haven't done that. Instead, I had opted for manually entering in the 30 digits.

**First question** I suppose, is is that right, or is there a way that using

> int[] hoursArray = {8, 24, 9, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8, 8, 9, 7, 9, 15, 6, 1, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8};

the data is automatically entered without the user manually entering the digits? Not sure if I'm reading the task right.

**Second question** is here is the code I have done. I can succesfully output the average and highest value, but I don't seem to be able to output the lowest value below 8 (ie, the value of 1 in there). How do I fix this?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace IntsArray
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] hours;           
            hours = new int[30];    

            int[] hoursArray = { 8, 24, 9, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8, 8, 9, 7, 9, 15, 6, 1, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8 };
            hours[0] = 8;
            hours[1] = 24;
            hours[2] = 9;
            hours[3] = 7;
            hours[4] = 6;
            hours[5] = 12;
            hours[6] = 10;
            hours[7] = 11;
            hours[8] = 23;
            hours[9] = 1;
            hours[10] = 2;
            hours[11] = 9;
            hours[12] = 8;
            hours[13] = 8;
            hours[14] = 9;
            hours[15] = 7;
            hours[16] = 9;
            hours[17] = 15;
            hours[18] = 6;
            hours[19] = 1;
            hours[20] = 7;
            hours[21] = 6;
            hours[22] = 12;
            hours[23] = 10;
            hours[24] = 11;
            hours[25] = 23;
            hours[26] = 1;
            hours[27] = 2;
            hours[28] = 9;
            hours[29] = 8;

            for (int index = 0; index < hours.Length; index++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter your hours: ");
                hours[index] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            int total = 0;      
            double average = 0; 
            for (int index = 0; index < hours.Length; index++)
            {
                total = total + hours[index];
            }

            average = (double)total / hours.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("Average = " + average.ToString("N2"));


            int high = hours[0]; 

            for (int index = 1; index < hours.Length; index++)
            {
                if (hours[index] > high)
                {
                    high = hours[index];
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Highest number = " + high);


            int low = hours[0];   

            for (int index = 0; index > hours.Length; index++)
            {
                if (hours[index] < low)
                {
                    low = hours[index];
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Lowest number = " + low);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What about min() max() and average() methods

Comment: To get lower number, change lower number for loop condition `index > hours.length` to `index < hours.length`

Comment: @un-lucky that worked for the minimum, thank you so much! Any comment as to my first question per chance?

Comment: Do you have a debugger? The best way to learn from own mistakes is to run your code through a debugger step by step and notice where the code doesn't do what you think you have planned for it to do. Asking someone else on the net to solve the problem for you is not so effective.

Comment: @Steve, I'm using visual studio, and that hadn't returned any errors for me. But do know that I'm only studying a very low level IT course and this is just 1 subject, so I haven't actually done any of this prior to this, so I'm probably much lower level than even being able to understand the error messages! Finding Stackoverflow has proved a godsend in my situation!

Comment: OK but knowing how to use the tools of the trade is fundamental. Press F9 on the first line of the min loop. Press F5 to run your program. Then press F10 to step over your code. No line of your loop is executed. Why? It is this required reasoning that allows you to avoid future errors of this kind.

Comment: Your professor has asked you to operate upon `hoursArray`. Why did you create the redundant array `hours`? Just operate upon `hoursArray`, or he might fail you! (and remove `hours` while you're at it, since you're supposed to create an MCVE and M stands for MINIMAL)

Comment: Hi @Seb, still very new at this so do forgive me. So remove the int[] hours you mean?

Comment: Remove `hours` and work on `hoursArray` (meaning change your logic to use `hoursArray` instead of `hours`).

Answer (score 1):

For getting the lowest number change following piece of code

```
    for (int index = 0; index > hours.Length; index++)
    {
        if (hours[index] < low)
        {
            low = hours[index];
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Lowest number = " + low);
```

To

```
    for (int index = 0; index < hours.Length; index++)
    {
        if (hours[index] < low)
        {
            low = hours[index];
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Lowest number = " + low);
```

Comment: Nicely spotted! Emphasis on the change would be great; it is rather difficult to spot.

Comment: Perhaps you could use comments on the line below the change: `// change this ---^` and `// ... to this ---^`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `Linq` extension methods

```
int[] hours = { 8, 24, 9, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8, 8, 9, 7, 9, 15, 6, 1, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8 };
Console.WriteLine("Average = {0:F2}", hours.Average());
Console.WriteLine("Highest number = {0}", hours.Max());
Console.WriteLine("Lowest number = {0}", hours.Min());
```

Output

> Average = 9.13
>
> Highest number = 24
>
> Lowest number = 1

Comment: This is nice... but I have a feeling the professor had a different lesson in mind; students need to know what's happening behind the scenes of the Linq... once they understand that much we can safely say "and here's a bit of syntax sugar for that".